How to run that example project in intellij?
I am trying to fire up a sample project from the book "Hands-On RESTful API Design Patterns and Best Practices" on a freshly downloaded intellij IDEA community edition environment.
I have installed the latest version of the JDK and maven.
I download the project from the git repository using the "New project from version control..." option.
Link to the project:
https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-RESTful-API-Design-Patterns-and-Best-Practices
After downloading, I cannot fire up the program. The console throws a series of errors as below:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=56045:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\48693\IdeaProjects\API\Chapter03\investor-services\target\classes;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-actuator\1.4.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\1.4.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.4.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.4.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\1.4.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.9\logback-classic-1.1.9.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.9\logback-core-1.1.9.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.22\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.22\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.22\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.17\snakeyaml-1.17.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-actuator\1.4.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-actuator-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.6.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\1.4.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\1.4.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.11\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\8.5.11\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.11.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\8.5.11\tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\5.2.4.Final\hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.0.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.3\classmate-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.8.6\jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.3.6.RELEASE\spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.6.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.6.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.3.6.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.6.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-xml\2.8.6\jackson-dataformat-xml-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.8.6\jackson-core-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.8.6\jackson-annotations-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations\2.8.6\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\stax2-api\3.1.4\stax2-api-3.1.4.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\woodstox\woodstox-core\5.0.3\woodstox-core-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.22\slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar;C:\Users\48693\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.6.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar com.books.chapters.restfulapi.patterns.chap3.springboot.InvestorServicesApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.4.RELEASE)

2024-04-19 23:55:15.938  INFO 25656 --- [           main] .b.c.r.p.c.s.InvestorServicesApplication : Starting InvestorServicesApplication on Piotrek with PID 25656 (C:\Users\48693\IdeaProjects\API\Chapter03\investor-services\target\classes started by 48693 in C:\Users\48693\IdeaProjects\API)
2024-04-19 23:55:15.940  INFO 25656 --- [           main] .b.c.r.p.c.s.InvestorServicesApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2024-04-19 23:55:15.983  INFO 25656 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1115ec15: startup date [Fri Apr 19 23:55:15 CEST 2024]; root of context hierarchy
2024-04-19 23:55:16.437 ERROR 25656 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.books.chapters.restfulapi.patterns.chap3.springboot.InvestorServicesApplication
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:403) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:249) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:281) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at com.books.chapters.restfulapi.patterns.chap3.springboot.InvestorServicesApplication.main(InvestorServicesApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:119) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:107) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:393) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @222545dc
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:388) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:203) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:54) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:44) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted

2024-04-19 23:55:16.437  INFO 25656 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1115ec15: startup date [Fri Apr 19 23:55:15 CEST 2024]; root of context hierarchy
2024-04-19 23:55:16.438  WARN 25656 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1115ec15: startup date [Fri Apr 19 23:55:15 CEST 2024]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:417) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:819) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at com.books.chapters.restfulapi.patterns.chap3.springboot.InvestorServicesApplication.main(InvestorServicesApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

2024-04-19 23:55:16.438 ERROR 25656 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1115ec15: startup date [Fri Apr 19 23:55:15 CEST 2024]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1009) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:819) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at com.books.chapters.restfulapi.patterns.chap3.springboot.InvestorServicesApplication.main(InvestorServicesApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]


Process finished with exit code 1


I have tried changing the dependencies in the pom, but so far without success. Could someone please help me with firing up this project? I would be very grateful.
I try to find out solution on StackOverflow

This question will [likely] be around for a long time so saying freshly downloaded intellij IDEA community edition and I have installed the latest version of the JDK will not reflect what you are actually using in a few months' (or even weeks) time. I think you should [edit] your question and post the actual verions numbers (for IntelliJ and JDK) of what you are actually using.

I am unfamiliar with the book Hands-On RESTful API Design Patterns and Best Practices but any good computer programming related book will state what versions of software products (and frameworks) the book's sample code was tested on. Does that book not state those details? Or did you not see them?

First of all, I need to remind you that the Spring Boot version in your linked Git repository is quite outdated. The repository contains Spring Boot 1.x, while the popular versions now are 2.x or 3.x. (So, you might want to consider if your learning materials are a bit out-of-date.)
If you need to run https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-RESTful-API-Design-Patterns-and-Best-Practices/tree/master/Chapter03/investor-services, then you should be using Java 8, not Java 22.
First, you'll need to download Java 8, and then switch the Java version that the project runs on in IDEA. To do this: IDEA-> File -> Project Structure -> Project -> SDK.

Thank you for your answer. That works! I keep in mind that the version of spring boot library is outdated but the most important for me is run the code and understand how approach presented in the book works in practice.
